# R Script : "Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type double"

Tags: r, azure-machine-learning-service

I am facing a issue while doing R Script in Azure MIL and error is
i.e. "Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type double"

My code is

```
dataset1 <-maml.mapInputPort(2)
dataset3 <-maml.mapInputPort(1)
Z <- as.numeric((dataset3),stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
Y <- mdBinaryDesign(Z,4,dataset1)
Y.aggregate=mdBinaryToAggregateDesign(Y)
survey.design=mdDesignNames(Y.aggregate, dataset1)
data.set <- as.data.frame(survey.design)
maml.mapOutputPort("data.set")
```

The issue in coming while assigning value to Z variable. dataset3 has simple numeric data i.e. "5" , which acts as a input to my model.

[image]

Comment: This is not reproducible and the structure of the data is not know. Where exactly is the error occurring?

Comment: The error is occuring while model is running , Particular when Z variable is assigned value it generates the error .  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwVDR.png Critical]  .   Error: Error 0063: The following error occurred during evaluation of R script:
---------- Start of error message from R ----------
(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'


(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
----------- End of error message from R -----------

Answer (score 3):

You can't do `as.numeric(dataset3)`. This is a data frame, and data frames can potentially contain multiple columns. Assuming your data only has one column and you want it as a vector, do

```
as.numeric(dataset3[[1]])
```

Comment: Hey I tried same , but i am getting error i.e. ---------- Start of error message from R ----------
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Here's what you can do. Run your code on your local machine first. When you're sure it works, copy and paste it into the AML R box, and change the variable names to fit.

Comment: The problem is my code needs inputs (Total three inputs to run) , they run perfectly fine on local machine , but for deployment/final purpose i want my model to have dynamic inputs (for which i am planning to use webservices). Once i use it , it does not works.

Comment: Do i use "  Z <- as.numeric(dataset3[[1]]stringsasFactors=True) ", but it gives me the same error.

Comment: Also if the dataframe has multiples columns you can use: apply(dataset3, 2 , as.numeric)