# Trouble coercing data frame to look like an object from the package "DOSE"; my as.numeric() object looks different

Tags: r, dplyr, coercion

I'm having some trouble trying to coerce a dataframe into data provided from the R [package DOSE](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/DOSE.html) so I can run [GO over-representation test](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/clusterProfiler/inst/doc/clusterProfiler.html) from the package [clusterProfiler](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/clusterProfiler.html)

The clusterProfiler vignette uses `geneList` from the DOSE package; it's class is numeric, but it's somehow linked a gene expression count with gene id.

You can see the data by doing the following:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("DOSE")
data(geneList, package="DOSE")
class(geneList)
[1] "numeric"

dput(head(geneList))
structure(c(4.57261268231107, 4.51459371540294, 4.41821798112707, 
4.14407518193211, 3.87625800905113, 3.67785700608222), .Names = c("4312", 
"8318", "10874", "55143", "55388", "991"))
```

I have a data.frame with two columns:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Gene_symbol = c(5339L, 1778L, 79026L, 5591L, 23224L, 
23195L), HAP1_pc = c(170, 253, 221.5, 231, 163.5, 172)), .Names = c("Gene_symbol", 
"HAP1_pc"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

When I try to coerce this data frame into a numeric class it gives me an error:

```
df2 <- as.numeric(df)
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I searched Stack Overflow for this error and found a suggestion from [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40377504/r-script-error-list-object-cannot-be-coerced-to-type-double):

```
as.numeric(df[[1]])
[1]  5339  1778 79026  5591 23224 23195
```

Of course this only returns column one (gene id).

By reason, if I replaced it with 2 it should return column 2 (gene expression)

```
as.numeric(df[[2]])
[1] 170.0 253.0 221.5 231.0 163.5 172.0
```

Indeed it did.

What confuses me is when I try specifying a range it returns the second row of column one:

```
as.numeric(df[[1:2]])
[1] 1778
```

At the bottom of this post someone said the above solution only works for one column (which appears to be the case); however, their suggestion for multiple columns (below) does not work as it returns class `matrix`:

```
apply(df, 2 , as.numeric)
     Gene_symbol HAP1_pc
[1,]        5339   170.0
[2,]        1778   253.0
[3,]       79026   221.5
[4,]        5591   231.0
[5,]       23224   163.5
[6,]       23195   172.0
```

I tried converting this matrix to numeric but this doesn't work either.

```
foo <- apply(df, 2 , as.numeric)
bar <- as.numeric(foo)
bar
[1]  5339.0  1778.0 79026.0  5591.0 23224.0 23195.0   170.0   253.0   221.5   231.0   163.5   172.0
```

Comparing the dput of geneList and my data the first apparent difference is that mine is `list` so i try to `unlist()` before `as.numeric()`

```
as.numeric(unlist(df))
 [1]  5339.0  1778.0 79026.0  5591.0 23224.0 23195.0   170.0   253.0   221.5   231.0   163.5   172.0
```

Same result as converting the matrix to numeric above.

Next apparent thing from the two `dput()`'s is that while my data has `.Name` as the headers the geneList `.Name` is one for every value in column 1. This is likely where the problem lies; however, I'm not sure what to do about it.

How can one do this with base R or using `dplyr'? You're help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that you are doing it in a wrong way. Can you try whether `df_geneList <- setNames(df$HAP1_pc, df$Gene_symbol)` works?

Comment: Thank you @mt1022 this works perfectly!